# test with expected exception is shown as failed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, junit, ejb

I have a small junit4 test that expect an exception.
this the code:

```
  @Test(expected = EntityVide.class)
    public void testPing() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("ping");
        int in = 0;
      int expResult = 1;
        int result = instance.ping(in);

    }
```

When i run the test it showed as a failed one .
I have already added @RunWith(JUnit4ClassRunner.class) but nothing changed .
I'm using netbeans 7.0 and junit 4.

Thanks .

Comment: Does your class extend `junit.TestCase`? If so, it will run as a JUnit 3 test, even if you add the `@Test` annotation. To check, simply rename your method to something that doesn't start with `test`: if it's no longer executed, then you're running it with a JUnit 3 runner.

Comment: Does it actually throw an exception?

Comment: Please provide more implementation information, as far as we can see you are not throwing any exception.

Comment: instance.ping() throw EntityVide expcetion . I'm runing a junit4 test .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expected` attribute of @Test annotation is for expected *exceptions*. Sometimes you want your test to throw exception of certain type. In 3.* version of JUnit you had to write `try/catch` block yourself. In Junit 4 you can mark this test with annotation.

Your test does not throw exception, so it fails because you said that you are expecting exception of type `EntityVide`. Remove this attribute and use `Assert.assertEquals()` to validate your result.